# What are the arguments to random.randint?

Tags: python

What are the 0 and -1 doing here?

```
import random

message = ['It is certain',
'It is decidedly so',
'Yes definitely',
'Reply hazy try again',
'Ask again later',
'Concentrate and ask again',
'My reply is no',
'Outlook not so good',
'Very doubtful']

print(message[random.randint(0, len(message) - 1)])
```

Comment: Note that `random.choice(message)` would be cleaner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We do not care about your level of experience or about your own assessment of the question - we care about **the question**, which you should *clearly ask* in the body of the post as well. You should make it clear what *steps you have taken* to try to understand the problem (for example, did you try *reading the documentation* for `random.randint`?).

Comment: The Python documentation will answer your question about this and all other functions you have questions about

Comment: Random integer in range [a, b]. So in this case, it is a to b minus 1. Where b is the length of the message. Why -1? Because message is a list and list items start at zero, whilst the range is the length of the message, so that must be adjusted by -1 or there could be an index error.

Answer (score 1):

`random.randint(0, len(message) - 1)]` is generating a random number between zero and (length of array-1), the -1 acts to keep the generated number within the bounds of array since arrays in python are indexed starting from zero. Thus, the index at the end of the array would be all the items - 1 since the first index is 0, not 1. If you ran `messages[length]` it would give you a bounds error. This random number is being used to print a message from the list that corresponds to the number.

Answer (score 0):

Your `randint` command gets 2 inputs `(start, end)` and during execution gives a random integer output using this range.
So in your snippet the starting value is `0` and the end value is `the lenght of your message minus 1`.
Also you need to remember that the last value is not included.

```
[x for x in range(0, 4)]
```

[0, 1, 2, 3]